# What's best way to display default view for 'No internet connection' each time navigate to any of view controllers?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift

If inserting the snippet code for checking and displaying the default view in the case of no internect connect at the beginning of viewWillAppear: method of each view controllers, it would make the ton of boilerplate code. So, I'd like to ask:

1. Is there a way to centralize this snippet code in one place and automatically inject into any of view controllers right after be called to display.
2. In the case of no internet connection, how to display the default view instead of the view of view controller?

Comment: UIAlertController: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/ios/874/uialertcontroller#t=2016111709002474564

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. First you have a to create a seperate view for 'No Internet screen'.
2. Create a BaseViewController in which, you will add a logic of hide/show no internet screen.
3. And all your apps viewcontroller are derived from this  'BaseViewController' and initialize this 'No Internet screen' and hide/show depends of internet Or API fails

Thats it.

Comment: exactly what I said earlier.

Answer (score 1):

Simple make a BaseViewController in which you implement the code to show or not the NoInternetConnection message.
It can be a simple UILabel that you add on top of other views.
Then inherit this class when you create a view controller that needs this common behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a `placeholder` view for `no net connection` state,
and you should think about easy to use for you and others, that's all.

There is a demo for you:https://github.com/liaodalin19903/LMLNonetAnimationPlaceholderView

You can learn how to create a better more `no net connection` placeholder VIEW